# How can I manage that a C# MDI Parent has Scrollbars, when the MDI Client is maximized?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a MDI Parent `Form 1` and an MDI Child `Form 2`

The `Form 2` has a `MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(568, 453);` set.

And as long as the MDI Child is not maximized everything works fine(the MDI Parent shows scrollbars).

[image: MDI Parent and Child]

As soon as I maximize the MDI Child, the scrollbars disappear and i cannot access the rest of the Controls on the `Form 2` in the lower Right Corner(the MDI Parent doesnt show Scrollbars).

[image: Maximizied Mdi Child]

I couldn't find any solution for this problem, i would be glad for any help or pointers. I would even be open for an other approach.

Comment: I believe your child form has been resized to fit in the parent form.  You'll need to use its resize event in order to make you child form work within the parent.  You could probably also set minimum sizes on each to make sure the user doesn't make it any smaller than is usable.

Comment: You must set the child form's AutoScroll property to True.  To avoid seeing its scrollbars when it is not maximized, and only scroll with the parent's scrollbars, you need to set its MinimizeSize property large enough.  All simple to do from the designer.

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF  thanks for your Pointer, Set minimum size on only the child doesnt work and setting it on the parent wont work. I probalbly will have to go with the resize event. I was looking for something easy and not custom coded. I any case thank you!

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your input, but I need the parent to be resizeable (very small), will will probably handcode the on the resize even, if i dont find something better in the next days. :)

Answer (score 0):

The MDI parent never shows scroll bars if the MDI children are maximized, as then technically no MDI child leaves the MDI client area (either no or all MDI children are maximized).

If you need automatic scrolling for maximized MDI children, you need to configure your MDI children to perform auto scrolling, too.